# Azure Data Storage Access from Databrikcs

Tags: azure, apache-spark, azure-storage, databricks

I can not access Azure Data Lake Storage from Databrikcs.

I have no premium Azure Databricks service.  I am trying to access ADLS Gen 2 Directly as per latest documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/data-sources/azure/adls-gen2/azure-datalake-gen2-sp-access#access-adls-gen2-directly

- I have granted the service principle "Contributor permissions" on this account

This is the Error message from notebook:
`Operation failed: &#34;This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.&#34;, 403, GET, https://geolocationinc.dfs.core.windows.net/instruments?upn=false&amp;resource=filesystem&amp;maxResults=500&amp;timeout=90&amp;recursive=false, AuthorizationPermissionMismatch, &#34;This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission. ...;`

this is my spark config setup:

````
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.oauth.provider.type.<storage-account-name>.dfs.core.windows.net", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.ClientCredsTokenProvider")
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.id.<storage-account-name>.dfs.core.windows.net", "<application-id>")
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.secret.<storage-account-name>.dfs.core.windows.net", dbutils.secrets.get(scope="<scope-name>",key="<service-credential-key-name>"))
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.endpoint.<storage-account-name>.dfs.core.windows.net", "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<directory-id>/oauth2/token")```
````

Answer (score 2):

The correct role is "Storage Blob Data Contributor" not "Contributor".

Comment: I have both Contributor and Owner permissions. still not ok?

Comment: Have to be "Storage Blob Data Contributor/Reader/Owner"